# Node.js async/await proper use

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, async-await

I am a little new to Node.js and trying to understand the right usage for async/await. I have a function (in the controller) that manages the connection with the database and executes the simple query (SELECT * from a table).
So my question is which of these two codes has the right usage of async/await (both work)?

Code 1:

```
const drzaveLista = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        await pool.connect(async(err, client, done) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            await client.query("SELECT * FROM DRZAVE;", [], (err, result) => {
                done();
                if (err) throw err;
                res.render("drzave", {listaDrzava: result.rows});
            });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Code 2:

```
const drzaveLista = async (req, res) =>{
const client = await pool.connect();
try{
    const result = await client.query("SELECT * FROM DRZAVE;");
    res.render("drzave", {listaDrzava: result.rows});
} catch (err){
    console.log(`Greska ${err}`);
} finally {
    client.release();
}
};
```

P.S. If that matters, I am using PostgreSQL as a database.

Comment: I don't think errors will be handled correctly in the first one. Typically methods that support promises _and_ callbacks don't return a promise if a callback is provided.

Comment: It does handle errors. For example, if I enter the name of the table that doesn't exist. https://imgur.com/a/vxYw4JA

Comment: @Kalaba That's not error handling, that's crashing the application

Comment: The second snippet is correct. Use that, and only that.

Answer (score 0):

You need not pass callbacks while using `async` and `await`.

Code 2 is the correct usage, and how it is actually done.

There is another mechanism if you do not want your controller to be asynchronous.

```js
const drzaveLista = (req, res) =>{
    const client = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { 
        await pool.connect().then(_client => resolve(_client)).catch(err => reject(err));
    });

    try{
        const result = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { 
            await client.query("SELECT * FROM DRZAVE;").then(_result => resolve(_result)).catch(err => reject(err));
        });
        res.render("drzave", {listaDrzava: result.rows});
    } catch (err){
        console.log(`Greska ${err}`);
    } finally {
        client.release();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For now, I will stick with my 2. code (it's easier for reading and understanding)

Comment: This is patently wrong. [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!